# My Items button not working after upgrade to Sitecore 9.3

Tags: sitecore-client, upgrade

After upgrading from `Sitecore 9.0.2` to `Sitecore 9.3`, When clicking on `My Items` (Under Review Ribbon) it does not show the `My Items Dialog Box`. It is an OOTB function and does not have any customization on top of it.

[image]

I already checked a log file there is no error logged. Also tried to open the URL in a new tab and there was no response. The console is clean no errors.

At some point, it returns a timeout error as the request is in a pending state and never returns the response.

Any thoughts or feedback?

Comment: Try to compare files in Sitecore and Sitecore Module folder from the vanilla Sitecore 9.3 folders, or do this just replace once from vanilla and see if the issue is gone, if yes then compare and get that file

Comment: Does this still happen when you change your connection strings back to a copy of the vanilla core DB?

Comment: Thanks, @GauravAgarwal for your valuable input, I've compared and it looks all good with the files.

Comment: Thank you @MarcelGruber. Yes, it also happens with a vanilla DB connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding more details as per Anna's suggestion we got the fix from Sitecore Support.

I'd like to inform you that the latest cumulative hotfix for `Sitecore 9.3` includes a fix for bug `#332061`.

Please find the hotfix available at the following URL:
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001332

Be aware that the hotfix was built specifically for `Sitecore 9.3` Initial Release, and you should not install it on other Sitecore versions or in combination with other hotfixes unless explicitly instructed by Sitecore Support.

Note that you need to extract ZIP file contents to locate installation instructions and related files inside it. Unless stated differently in the installation instructions, the hotfix should be installed on CM instance and then synced with other instances using your regular development practices.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem on a Sitecore 9.3 website: every time someone was clicking the My items button, the page was freezing and eventually timing out.
It was happening because the SQL query for getting locked items goes through all items in the DB and the content tree on this website was quite large.

This issue has a reference number 332061 and it is fixed in Sitecore 10.0. Here is the knowledge base article about this problem with solution for addressing it https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0285429

When I contacted Sitecore support, they recommended to install the platform hotfix **SC Hotfix 517664-1**. Unfortunately the link I had for it has expired, so if the solution from the knowledge base does not help, please reach out to Sitecore Support and mention to them that this is a known issue and you need a hotfix for it.

Comment: Thanks, @AnnaGevel. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, KB link solution did not work for us. I reached out to Sitecore Support. I'll post updates here once received. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update Sumit, hopefully you will get get a fix soon!